# curl --resolve appears to do nothing

Tags: dns, curl

The `--help` output for curl lists a `--resolve` option, which states

```
--resolve <host:port:address> Force resolve of HOST:PORT to ADDRESS
```

I'm not having any luck getting it to work though.  The basic command I'm trying to run is

```
curl --resolve foo.example.com:443:localhost https://foo.example.com:443/
```

and I keep getting the response `Couldn't resolve host 'foo.example.com'`.  I want do do this because I'm testing a certificate for foo.example.com, but I'm not testing it on the actual server.  Instead, I'm testing it on a dummy machine.  I know that I can edit `/etc/hosts` so that foo.example.com resolves to localhost, but this curl approach seems like it would be the "correct" way to go, if I could make it work.

Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It appears that the `address` needs to be a numeric IP address, not a hostname.

Try this:

```
curl --resolve foo.example.com:443:127.0.0.1 https://foo.example.com:443/
```

Comment: This makes sense because in the DNS world, `resolve` means "get an IP address from a name".

Answer (score 7):

Some additional help in troubleshooting:

Ensure you're listing the right port for the protocol: http=80; https=443 & etc.

Also `curl -v` will give the HEADER information for the response server which can be helpful.

```
$ curl -v --resolve foo.example.com:443:127.0.0.1 https://foo.example.com:443/
## The client request headers prepended by >
> OPTIONS /v1/..
> HOSTS foo.example.com
## The server response prepended by <
< HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented
## The html returned
<H1>Unsupported Request</H1>
```

Basically in this case the `OPTIONS HTTP` method was not implemented at the edge server for the CDN.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. Very strange, but it seems like it depends on the version. I checked one server with `curl --manual | grep resolve` for version 7.19.7 and the `--resolve` parameter is missing.
In version 7.29.0, I have this parameter, and resolving is working fine.